# SQL & PHP: UPDATE row doesn't work

Tags: php, sql, submit

So I have to make a php page that approves/rejects some information taken by a specific row in a database. If the Admin that sees the info Approves it, he puts some extra values and updates the specific row in the database (these extra values are 0 before approval), but it ultimately doesn't work. I think the problem is with the approve.php file the submit form redirects to, i think it doesn't read the values the Admin inputs.

Here is the form (lecturermeet.php):

```
 <div class="wrapper col3">
 <div class="container">
  <h1>Pending Meeting Submissions</h1>

    <?php
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("dissdb") or die(mysql_error());
    $statuscheck = 0;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT status FROM meeting WHERE status = '$statuscheck'");
    if ($result != NULL) {
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT id,username,date,subject,report FROM meeting WHERE status =       '$statuscheck'");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    $uploader = $row['username'];
    $date = $row['date'];
    $subject = $row['subject'];
    $report = $row['report'];
    $id = $row['id'];
    echo ' <font size=6> <p>Meeting: #' .$id. ' </font><br><br>Submitted by: '.$uploader.'<br>Date: ' .$date. '<br>Subject: ' .$subject. '<br>Report: '  .$report. '<br> <br></p>'   ;

    $showbuttons = 1;

    if($showbuttons == 1) : ?>


    <form>
      Meeting #:
      <input type="number" name="id" id="id" value='$id' min="1" max="20">
    </form>

    <form>
      Project Progression Status (between 1 and 6):
      <input type="number" name="progress" id="progress" min="1" max="6">
    </form>

    <form>
    <br>  Effort Shown (between 1 and 6):
      <input type="number" name="effort" id="effort" min="1" max="6">
    </form>

    <form>
    <br>  Dissertation Projection (between 1 and 6):
      <input type="number" name="projection" id="projection" min="1" max="6">
    </form>

    <form>
    <br>  Lecturer Satisfaction (between 1 and 6):
      <input type="number" name="satisfaction" id="satisfaction" min="1" max="6">
    </form>

    <form>
    <br>  Overall (between 1 and 10):
      <input type="number" name="mark" id="mark" min="1" max="10">
    <br><br><br></form>




    <form action="approve.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">
    </form>

    <label for="rejectinfo"><br><br><br>Rejection comments:</label>
    <textarea name="rejectinfo" cols="60" rows="7" id="rejectinfo" ></textarea>

    <p><form action="reject.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="reject" value="Reject">
    <br><br></form></p>
    <?php endif;
    }} ?>






 </div>
 </div>
```

and here is the approve.php the form redirects to in order to update the specific row:

```
 <?php



  require "config.php";
  require "lecturerarea.php";

  $id = $_POST['id'];
   $progress = $_POST['progress'];
    $effort = $_POST['effort'];
    $projection = $_POST['projection'];
    $satisfaction = $_POST['satisfaction'];
    $mark = $_POST['mark'];
    $status = 1;
    mysql_connect("localhost","root","") or die(mysql_error());
   mysql_select_db("dissdb") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_query("UPDATE meeting SET 'progress'='$progress', 'effort'='$effort',
'projection'='$projection', 'satisfaction'='$satisfaction', 'mark'='$mark', 'status'='$status'     WHERE id = '$id'");
    echo "The meeting submission is approved! <br> Redirecting now ....";
        header("Refresh: 3; lecturerarea.php");



 ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried the same query inside phpmyAdmin and see if it gives you any errors?Alot the forms has to have a 'method='post''

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). *They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation)*. See the [red box](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). [This article](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which.

Comment: Also i agree with @JayBlanchard PDO is the way to go.

Comment: @Colosuslol nope, the 'method=post' didn't work either. Either way, the errors show: 
Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 8

Notice: Undefined index: progress in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: effort in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 10

Notice: Undefined index: projection in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 11

Notice: Undefined index: satisfaction in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 12

Comment: about PDO, i don't have the time needed to switch the way I worked, I have to submit this tomorrow evening :(

Comment: Okay, why not make everything in one form instead of have 5 forms?

Comment: @Colosuslol how can i do this? Please write the code if you can, I started PHP just about 3 days ago.

Comment: @tototororo Have you consulted my answer given below? I posted it over 10 mins. ago.

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes fred, I had already tried that before posting. I think the error is in the forms - it doesn't receive the extra values correctly so when I assign them into variables e.g.  $progress = $_POST['progress'];
i receive an error like Undefined index: progress in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 9

what can i do about this?

Comment: @tototororo Reload my answer and look under the **Edit**, it states that you have multiple form tags. You should only use the one. Plus it needs to be `method="post"` for all of them.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes from around your column names. Those are not the right [**identifiers**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifier-qualifiers.html).

I.e.: `SET 'progress'='$progress'`

which should read as (using backticks example)

```
 SET `progress`='$progress' // etc.
```

or remove the quotes and do the same for the others.

```
 SET progress='$progress' // etc.
```

Having [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on, would have signaled that.

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Also `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

### Edit:

You also have multiple `<form></form>` tags. Put everything inside the one `<form>...</form>` plus you need to specify the method.

```
<form method="post">
```

`<form>` defaults to `GET` if omitted.

All of your variables used for DB insertion, are `$_POST`.

This is equal to a `GET` method

```
<form>
<br>  Overall (between 1 and 10):
  <input type="number" name="mark" id="mark" min="1" max="10">
<br><br><br></form>
```

and will not be entered in DB.

It should read as

```
<form method="post">
<br>  Overall (between 1 and 10):
  <input type="number" name="mark" id="mark" min="1" max="10">
<br><br><br></form>
```

and do the same for the others.

As for the `headers already sent`, remove the `echo` from above the `header` or use a meta refresh if you want it to echo the message.

---

Ideally, this is what you should be doing:

```
<form action="approve.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
Meeting #:
<input type="number" name="id" id="id" value='$id' min="1" max="20">

Project Progression Status (between 1 and 6):
<input type="number" name="progress" id="progress" min="1" max="6">

<br>  Effort Shown (between 1 and 6):
<input type="number" name="effort" id="effort" min="1" max="6">

<br>  Dissertation Projection (between 1 and 6):
<input type="number" name="projection" id="projection" min="1" max="6">

<br>  Lecturer Satisfaction (between 1 and 6):
<input type="number" name="satisfaction" id="satisfaction" min="1" max="6">

<br>  Overall (between 1 and 10):
<input type="number" name="mark" id="mark" min="1" max="10">
<br><br><br>

<input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">

<label for="rejectinfo"><br><br><br>Rejection comments:</label>
<textarea name="rejectinfo" cols="60" rows="7" id="rejectinfo" ></textarea>

<input type="submit" name="reject" value="Reject">
<br><br>
</form>
```

---

***Sidenote:***

Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).
Use [**prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

Answer (score 0):

Okay you are getting the the errors because when you are clicking submit approve you only take the values of that form, so if you want the data of projection and the others make something like it.

```
<form action="approve.php" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="submit" name="approve" value="Approve">
 <br>  Dissertation Projection (between 1 and 6):
      <input type="number" name="projection" id="projection" min="1" max="6">
    </form>
```

And the other inputs.

Comment: YES that's it, it works!!!!!!!!!!!!!

last thing, about redirecting, i have the following code `
     echo "The meeting submission is approved! <br> Redirecting now ....";
    header("Refresh: 3; lecturerarea.php"); `


and i receive the following error
`Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\lecturerarea.php:128) in C:\xampp\htdocs\softdevone\approve.php on line 20`

how can i fix this?

Comment: Add ob_start at the begining of the script